# Physical Meaning For Total Cross-Section

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I am trying to understand what is the total cross-section of a proton with a photon, or, a proton with a neutrino.

I am confused about how a proton and a neutrino would have any interaction in this case; how would a neutrino even interact?

Comment: In the second sentence, do you mean neutron or neutrino?

Comment: *what would these two opposite charges even do* What two charges? In every interaction you mention, there is only one charged particle. The photon, neutrino, and neutron are all neutral.

Comment: I mean total cross-section for a proton with a photon, and a proton with a neutrino. 


Sorry, I was thinking about two different things in the last question, that will be edited once I respond to this.

Comment: Neutrinos interact through the weak force

Comment: The neutrino can exchange a $W$ or $Z$ boson with one of the quarks in the proton. The cross-section is a way of expressing how likely this is to happen.

Comment: What would happen to the proton-photon at the cross-section?